# How to make angular input controls readonly from typescript?

Tags: angular

I have the following in HTML

```
  <mat-form-field [appearance]="matFormFieldAppearance" style="margin-left:10px;width:50%">
    <mat-label>Type</mat-label>
    <mat-select formControlName="TypeId" required>
      <mat-option *ngFor="let item of TypeList" [value]="item.Id">
        {{item.Title}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>


  <mat-form-field [appearance]="matFormFieldAppearance" style="margin-left:10px;width:50%">
    <mat-label>Category</mat-label>
    <mat-select formControlName="CategoryeId" required>
      <mat-option *ngFor="let item of CategoryList" [value]="item.Category">
        {{item.Category}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
```

In TypeScript, MatDialog receives data and if Field1 is not null then, I want the form fields be put in ReadOnly

```
this.K = this.matdialogData;
if (this.K.Field1 !== null)
{
          this.myForm.controls.CategoryeId.ReadOnly(); //Something like this
          this.myForm.controls.TypeId.ReadOnly();//Something like this
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to disable the input controls? It is not clear what exactly you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
this.myForm.controls['CategoryeId'].disable();
this.myForm.controls['TypeId'].disable();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can disable the fields to make them read-only.

```
this.myForm.controls.CategoryeId.disable();
this.myForm.controls.TypeId.disable();
```

Also, you can add a class to mat-form-field with style pointer-events-none to make the fields read-only.

Comment: I get the warning. It looks like you're using the disabled attribute with a reactive form directive. If you set disabled to true
      when you set up this control in your component class, the disabled attribute will actually be set in the DOM for
      you. We recommend using this approach to avoid 'changed after checked' errors.
       
      Example: 
      form = new FormGroup({
        first: new FormControl({value: 'Nancy', disabled: true}, Validators.required),
        last: new FormControl('Drew', Validators.required)
      });

Comment: I have <mat-icon matChipRemove>cancel</mat-icon> to which I am unable to mention disabled(); It throws error.

Comment: It is suggesting you to use disabled in the form control.You can try using FormControl({value: '' ", disabled: this.K.Field1}) where you define the form control in the component.For mat-icon you can add a class with pointer-events-none to make the it read-only.